# Where is the difference between onError and CatchError in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

The only difference I see is that onError also gets the Stacktrace passed as a parameter.
In which situations would you choose one other the other?

Comment: that link has not mentioned any of the difference.

Answer (score 19):

```
Future<T> onError<E extends Object>(FutureOr<T> Function(E, StackTrace) handleError, {bool Function(E)? test})

Future<T> catchError(Function onError, {bool Function(Object error)? test});
```

`onError` is effectively a more precisely typed version of `catchError`.

So, with `onError` you can catch specific error types and specify a correctly typed error handler function, rather than all types and just a Function with `catchError`.

Comment: Expanding the answer: `.onError<E extends Object>` would be the equivalent of the clause `on Exception catch (e)` syntax, while `.catchError` would be the entire `catch (e)` declaration of the try-catch.

Answer (score 2):

in `onError` the error will be considered as Uncaught Exception, whereas `catchError` is not.